# Empty ConnectionHeader in MessageEvent (C++)

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to get the publisher of a topic message in a C++ subscriber.

However, when I subscribe to the topic via a `MessageEvent<>` callback and try to get the connection header via `event.getConnectionHeaderPtr()`, I only get a nullptr. This happens when publishing from a C++ node and via `rostopic pub ...`.

It works when the subscriber is a python node (I am able to get the publisher name via `data._connection_header["callerid"]`).
I am not able to find further resources online to solve the issue. Does anyone have an idea on what could be the cause?

[This question](https://answers.ros.org/question/200187/empty-connection-header-topic/) seems to be related, but was fixed (the fix should be included in my system).

System information:

- Platform: Ubuntu 18, kernel 4.15.0-65-generic
- ROS Melodic (from official packages)

Code excerpts:

```
// in namespace basic_topic
template <class Msg>
struct SubscriberCallback
{
    SubscriberCallback();
    void operator()(const ros::MessageEvent<Msg>& event);
};

template <class Msg>
void SubscriberCallback<Msg>::operator()(const ros::MessageEvent<Msg>& event)
{
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Publisher: " << event.getPublisherName() 
                    << " header: " << event.getConnectionHeaderPtr());
    typename Msg::ConstPtr msg = event.getConstMessage();
    // ...
}

class Subscriber
{
public:
    // ...
    void subscribe(ros::NodeHandle& node, uint32_t bufferSize = 10);

private:
    // ...
    ros::Subscriber subInt32;
};

void Subscriber::subscribe(ros::NodeHandle& node, uint32_t queueSize)
{    
    // ...
    subInt32 = node.subscribe<std_msgs::Int32>("Int32", queueSize, SubscriberCallback<std_msgs::Int32>());
}
```

In main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    static const std::string nodeName = "test_basic_subscriber";
    static const uint32_t queueSize = 100;

    ros::init(argc, argv, nodeName);
    ros::NodeHandle node;

    basic_topic::Subscriber subscriber;
    subscriber.subscribe(node, queueSize);

    ros::Time last = ros::Time::now();
    const ros::Duration duration(0.5);

    while (ros::ok())
    {
        ros::spinOnce();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Result when running:

```
[ INFO] [1571830014.487512531]: Publisher: unknown_publisher header: 0
```

Example publish via `rostopic pub`: (Result is the same as when publishing from C++ node)

```
rostopic pub /Int32 std_msgs/Int32 "data: 42"
```

Example subscriber node in python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int32

def callback(data):
    # type: (Int32) -> None
    print("Received {} from node {}.".format(
        data.data,
        data._connection_header["callerid"]))

def run_subscriber():
    rospy.init_node("basic_test_subscriber")
    sub = rospy.Subscriber("Int32", Int32, callback)
    # pub = rospy.Publisher("BasicTopic/reportInt", Int32, queue_size=10)
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_subscriber()
```

Result when publishing from `rostopic pub`:

```
Received 42 from node /rostopic_11868_1571830133181.
```

Result when publishing from C++ node:

```
Received 42 from node /test_basic_publisher.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335977/empty-connectionheader-in-messageevent-(c++)/) by [RainerK](https://answers.ros.org/users/47747/rainerk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-10-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could solve the problem. The callback function had to be casted explicitly to the correct `boost::function` type:

```
void Subscriber::subscribe(ros::NodeHandle& node, uint32_t queueSize)
{    
    // ...
    using BoostCallback = boost::function<void(const ros::MessageEvent<std_msgs::Int32>&>;
    subInt32 = node.subscribe<std_msgs::Int32>("Int32", queueSize, BoostCallback(SubscriberCallback<std_msgs::Int32>()));
}
```

I guess the internal overloading of `NodeHande::subscribe()` did not work properly for my case, causing invalid/uninitialized `MessageEvent`s to my callback.

---

Originally posted by [RainerK](https://answers.ros.org/users/47747/rainerk/) with karma: 66 on 2019-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3